# How to access partitioned pandas dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is my Python Code. I have a doubt in my code

I have partitioned the input dataframe based on country. But how to access each country data separately in a loop? (dfs[0], dfs1,..is not working)

```
  dfs = {k: v for k, v in df1.groupby ('country')}
```

Source Code:

```
import pypyodbc
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats

connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};''Server=GIRSQL.GIRCAPITAL.com;''Database=Tableau;''uid=SQL_User;pwd=Greentableau!')
cursor = connection.cursor()

real_earnings = []
real_price = []
CAPE = []

SQLCommand = ("SELECT * FROM [Tableau].[dbo].[Country_table1$]  Order by [Country] , [Date] ")
df1 = pd.read_sql_query(SQLCommand, connection)
total_rows = df1.iloc[:,1].count()

dfs = {k: v for k, v in df1.groupby ('country')}
print (dfs)

for j in range(0, 1):
    df = dfs['SPAIN']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate over the dictionary, you can iterate over its keys to access its values:

```
for k in dfs: # k is the key
    print(dfs[k]) # data associated with country `k`
```

Example:

```
In [1]: pack_of_cards = {'2': 2,'3': 3,'4': 4,'5': 5,'6': 6, \
   ...:                  '7': 7,'8': 7,'9': 9,'10': 10,'J': 10, \
   ...:                  'D': 10,'K': 10,'T': 10}

In [2]: for k in pack_of_cards:
   ...:     print(k, pack_of_cards[k])
   ...:     
3 3
T 10
J 10
9 9
...
```